# Does Knative on EKS support node autoscaler?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I wanted to know that does Knative on EKS supports the node autoscaler if yes do we need to set up cluster autoscaler or Knative itself scale the nodes?

I tried autoscaling the nodes by increasing the pods but did not work my question is that does Knative automatically scales nodes or do we have to set up any external plugins?

Comment: It worked and resolved the issue thank you

Comment: feel free to update the status of question by marking below answer accept if resolves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Knative** supports only two types of auto-scaling

- **KPA** - Knative Pod Autoscaler
- **HPA** - Horizontal Pod Autoscaler

So for Node auto scaling **Cluster Auto scaler** will be required to be installed into EKS.

Ref : https://knative.dev/docs/serving/autoscaling/autoscaler-types/